# phpmyadmin fails to show any content

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just updated phpmyadmin to the latest version. Config and Login looks fine. But the whole content only blinks for a second and is not shown anymore. So I still see the top menu, can switch the DB. I just a bit lost what could be the cause any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you recall what your old version was? Which webserver, web browser, and operating systems are you using? Can you try with a different browser? Are you using https? Do you see any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: Old Version: phpMyAdmin 4.9.10
Webserver: Apache2 only http on localhost
This is from the error.log: 
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.PHP message: phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
But www-data hast permisson on this directory.

Comment: Although there is no confgig.inc.php in this directory.